# How to define a superclass constraint for free monoids?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, superclass, type-constraints

Consider the following type class for free monoids.

```hs
class FreeMonoid f where
    inj :: a -> f a
    univ :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> f a -> m
```

`inj` injects a value into the free monoid, and `univ` is the universal property of free monoids.

Instances of this class should satisfy the following laws.

- **Identity**: `univ f . inj = f`
- **Free empty**: `univ f mempty = mempty`
- **Free append**: `univ f (m <> n) = univ f m <> univ f n`

Note that if `f` is an instance of `FreeMonoid` then `(f a)` must be an instance of `Monoid`. Otherwise, the last two laws don't make sense. So, how do I specify this constraint? Here's what I tried.

```hs
class Monoid (f a) => FreeMonoid f where
    inj :: a -> f a
    univ :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> f a -> m
```

Not having this constraint makes it inconvenient to use this class. For example, consider the following function.

```hs
mapFreeMonoid :: (FreeMonoid f, Monoid (f b)) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
mapFreeMonoid f = univ (inj . f)
```

Since `f` is an instance of `FreeMonoid`, we shouldn't have to specify the `Monoid (f b)` constraint. Ideally, we should be able to define the above function as follows.

```hs
mapFreeMonoid :: FreeMonoid f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
mapFreeMonoid f = univ (inj . f)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try experimenting with the `QuantifiedConstraints` extension.

```
class (forall a. Monoid (f a)) => FreeMonoid f where
   ...
```

Your code then compiles without the additional constraint.

```
mapFreeMonoid :: FreeMonoid f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
mapFreeMonoid f = univ (inj . f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the QuantifiedConstraints extension as chi’s answer said. Take a look at the analogous definition for free categories, the [CFree constraint here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-categories-0.2.0.2/docs/Control-Category-Free.html#t:CFree).